# C++ struct in a vector in an object(class)

Tags: c++, oop, vector, struct

was in this for few hours now and I cannot seem to find the right way to do this. I am creating a vector that will be populated with structs but I could not make it to work. I have tried making a struct and put the struct from the object in there but received an error. Anyways this is my work, I am really new into this so I hope you guys could help me out.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CBank.h"

int main()
{
    CBank bank;

    struct account = bank.account;

    bank.account.name = "Alpha Omega";
    bank.account.money = 15635.23;
    bank.account.pin = 3241;

    bank.add.push_back(account);
    return 0;
}
```

CBank.h

```
#ifndef CBANK_H
#define CBANK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class CBank
{
    public:
        CBank();

    private:
        struct account { std::string name;
                         float money;
                         short pin;
                       };
        std::vector<account> add;
};

#endif // CBANK_H
```

CBank.cpp

```
#include "CBank.h"

CBank::CBank()
{
    //ctor
}
```

Comment: I think you would be better off reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as you seem to have some basic misunderstanding on what types and values are.

Comment: Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be clear about the problem you face and post the exact error messages that you get and start with a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @CsuGouv Note that `account` is a type.

Comment: Hi there, sorry! I have now updated the main.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define a type (`account`) in the class. `account` is a type so you should not declare it in the class :

```
struct account { std::string name;
                 float money;
                 short pin;
               };
```

and then, the class becomes :

```
class CBank
{
    public:
        CBank();
        account acc;
        std::vector<account> add;
};
```

and the main :

```
int main()
{
    CBank bank;

    bank.acc.name = "Alpha Omega";
    bank.acc.money = 15635.23;
    bank.acc.pin = 3241;

    bank.add.push_back(bank.acc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "`account` is a type so you should not declare it in the class". Defining types within other types is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yep, but it is easier to understand it with the declaration of the type outside of the class for a beginner. I think he should learn to spot the difference between type and instance before declaring structures in classes. Maybe I am wrong..

Comment: This is so good! Thank you so much for this. I am now studying why this and that. Thank you again, @CsuGouv

Answer (score 0):

Your struct `account` and `add` vector are private members of `CBank`. To access them you need to make them public like your class constructor is.

Comment: Hi there and thank you for your response. Should it be okay to have the struct and the vector in the same class at the same time?

Comment: It should be fine however it would be good practice to put the `account` struct in a separate header file and include that in `CBank.h`.